# Calling a Julia function from C++ that takes a Julia callback function as an argument

Tags: c++, julia

I'd like to call a Julia function from C++. This Julia function takes another Julia function as an argument (a callback function). I'd like to write this callback function entirely in C++ too, and pass it directly to Julia, without declaring a name for it in Julia's name space, like how other primitive types are passed. Presumably the arguments to my C++ implementation of the callback function will have `jl_value_t *` as their types.

Can anyone provide me with an example of how to do this? The [embedded Julia example](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/examples/embedding.c) is pretty good, but it doesn't seem to illustrate this case.

Update: Revised and clarified based on Yakk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The example covers this case.

Here we call a c function:

```
jl_eval_string("println( ccall( :my_c_sqrt, Float64, (Float64,), 2.0 )
```

Which is defined at the top of the example.

Elsewhere there is an exampe of defining a julia function.  Define one that does a `ccall` into your c code.

```
jl_eval_string("my_func(x) = 2*x");
```

(Except instead of `2*x` it does `ccall(blah)`).

The take that julia function, and get a pointer to it (also in your linked example).

```
jl_function_t *func = jl_get_function(jl_base_module, "reverse!");
```

And pass it to the julia function expecting a callback.  Or, use an eval to pass it by name.

The C++ code will be passed `double`s and the like with this plan.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I see this could work, but I'd like to do it without creating a new function in Julia's name space (e.g., `my_func`). Seems like it would be cleaner that way, and that it should be possible for functions too, since it works that way for floats and ints---they get boxed and passed to Julia without creating global Julia handles. Is that possible for functions too?

Comment: Why is namespace an issue? Just use a password generator to get a name like vyQMNzqlL0ww9HCgjWBuqXmzRSvcaEeSSfnufJkvmzASjHcmOea3zDgLiVNMMaa

Comment: If you think efficiency would be an issue, you should probably write everything in the same language or rewrite your julia function to directly ccall your function. (A macro might make that psudo dynamic)

Comment: Efficiency and clarity are my main concerns. I was considering calling Julia from C++ pretty often, but I might be thinking about this the wrong way, at least if a hard coding the output of password generator is the cleanest way to do this.... Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: @jeff there could be a way to do what you want, but my knowledge if the problem is I read the tutorial you provided and noticed there was an answer to your problem there.  Have you profiled that this is a bottleneck, or do you just assume?

Comment: I'm with you---profiling is better than guessing typically. In this case, however, I'm trying to decide on a long-term strategy for mixing two code bases. Do I port one to the other language, or do I try mixing them? If I end up mixing julia and C++, it's hard to profile ahead of time all the possible ways they might mix as development progresses. If I could call any Julia function directly from C++, without overhead and without hacks, I'd lean towards mixing the languages rather than porting. If not, porting the Julia to C++ seems safer, though tedious.